# GroupBy Expression

Tags: c#, group-by

I have the following object(s) and I want to have a result that provides a collection of objects grouped by first category description and then grouped by subcategory description with:

Category(Count)
     SubCategory(Count)
     SubCategory(Count)

```
public class Posting
{
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategory
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**

So I have this working like so:

```
foreach (var category in col.GroupBy(x => x.Category.Description).Select(x => new { CategoryName = x.Key, Items = x }).OrderBy(x => x.CategoryName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(category.CategoryName);
                foreach (var subCategory in category.Items.GroupBy(x => x.SubCategory.Description).Select(x => new { SubCategoryName = x.Key }).OrderBy(x => x.SubCategoryName))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + subCategory.SubCategoryName);
                }
            }
```

But I would like to get this into one object graph, is that possible?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be pretty close, with the caveat that the `Key` field of the "inner" sub-category groupings is an anonymous type containing both the Category and SubCategory.  But, depending on what your application is doing, that might be a feature since you'll always have the Category available.

```
var results = col
    .GroupBy(posting => new
        {
            Category = posting.Category.Description,
            SubCategory = posting.SubCategory.Description
        })
    .GroupBy(group => group.Key.Category.Description);
```